# Disabling Sender to edit api the View

Tags: docusignapi

Actually the problem I'm facing is that I set the whole Document view using DocuSign API and i Don't want the sender to do any sort of editing on documents. I want that the sender should just be able to see the document in a non editable form and send it to the customer for signing.

Any Suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to create the envelope and its document(s) by using the API, and then obtain approval from a person before sending the envelope?

And you don't want the sender to be able to do any type of editing of the document or envelope?

I suggest:

1. Use the API to create the envelope in `Created` (draft) status.
2. Use the Envelopes::get API call to obtain the document(s)
3. Your app can then show the documents to the sender.
4. If the sender approves, then he or she presses a button in your app.
5. Then your app changes the envelope status to `Sent` and it will be sent to the first recipient.

#### Or

Add the "approver" as the first signer recipient. You could give them an initials tab.

Then, when they receive the envelope they either approve it being sent to the next person by initialing the document, or, to disapprove, they just don't initial it and it won't be sent onward.

Remember to use sequential routing.